# Problem with footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I want to add a footnote in my document. Unfortunately this does not always work. For example I have the following two documents:
Document1:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Test \footnote{http://www.erneuerbare-energien.de/EE/Redaktion/DE/Dossier/eeg.html?cms_docId=72462}


\end{document}
```

Document2:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Test\footnote{http://www.bmwi.de/DE/Themen/Energie/Europaische-und-internationale-Energiepolitik/europaeische-energiepolitik.html}


\end{document}
```

For document 1 I get 8 errors while compiling and no output PDF is produced whereas for document 2 I do not get a singel error and the output PDF looks like it should.

Comment: For the first I get the expected `! Missing $ inserted.` because of the `_` in the URL, the second runs without problems. You should add `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` and use `\url{http://...}` for the URLs.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx, by the way :)

Comment: You say the output of the second example "looks like it should". In fact, the line break LaTeX found is terrible, with the first line being seriously underfull. Better to encase the URL-like string in a `\url` wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

In both of your examples, the easiest fix is to load the `url` package with the option `hyphens`, viz.

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

and to encase the material the footnotes in `\url{...}` directives, i.e., to write

```
Test \footnote{\url{http://www.erneuerbare-energien.de/EE/Redaktion/DE/Dossier/eeg.html?cms_docId=72462}}
```

and

```
Test\footnote{\url{http://www.bmwi.de/DE/Themen/Energie/Europaische-und-internationale-Energiepolitik/europaeische-energiepolitik.html}}
```

The `\url` wrappers (i) do a good job of finding line breaks in long URL-like strings and (ii) remove the special meanings of characters such as `_`, `^`, `&`, and `#`.

The following screenshot shows the two footnotes generated by the proposed course of action.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}
Test.\footnote{\url{http://www.erneuerbare-energien.de/EE/Redaktion/DE/Dossier/eeg.html?cms_docId=72462}}

Test.\footnote{\url{http://www.bmwi.de/DE/Themen/Energie/Europaische-und-internationale-Energiepolitik/europaeische-energiepolitik.html}}
\end{document}
```